# Select element using selenium, java and Extjs framework

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to click on a button generated by Extjs framework. 
I have this html:

```
<a class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" id="button-1022" tabindex="0" componentid="button-1022" style="right: auto; top: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px;">

<span id="button-1022-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-default-toolbar-small ">

  <span id="button-1022-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-toolbar-small x-btn-text    x-btn-button-center ">

   <span id="button-1022-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-toolbar-small  " style=""></span><span id="button-1022-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-toolbar-small">Nuovo</span>

</span>
</span>
</a>
```

This code is generated by Extjs framework. I want to select the "Nuovo" text and then click. I am using Selenium (2.42.2) with Java:

```
e = driver.findElement(By.id("button-1022")); 
e.click();
```

Ok, it works but is too specific, I don't want do force the id.

So I am trying:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Nuovo')]/../../.."));
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Nuovo')]"));
```

With both solution I have this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Why using `By.id(..)` it works and using `xpath` I have the error?

Comment: What about more strict "//span[text()='Nuovo']", will it work? Your xpath looks valid though..